# Link html button to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXQ9U/) in which I want to link a button to the following Javascript code:

```
var computerChoice = math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0,5) {
    console.log("you lost")
} else {
    console.log("you've won"
}
```

So if I press the button, a random number should be generated leading to one of the two responses. How can I get this working?

Comment: Please read the [jQuery tutorial about basic event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/). That's what tutorials are there for, to teach you the basics of a library/framework/etc. Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn these basics. To learn more about event handling in general, I recommend the [quirksmode.org articles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: Capitalize the `m` in `Math`!

Comment: @Charlie given the question originally asked for, and the jsFiddle currently contains jQuery, I'd suggest reverting the edit you made.

Comment: Awesome DA, thanks a lot. One more thingie, what would be statement if I want to push a msgbox in stead of console.log (depending on the random numer, so fe, a msgbox with : you've lost when the number is <0,5

Comment: @DA. Now that it's tagged correctly, there's no need to include the text "I have a question about jquery."

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    // insert your JS here
})
```

To elaborate...the above is attaching a click event listener to your button. This is the very essence of jQuery: select an item from the DOM, attach logic to it. The above assumes you gave your button an `id` of 'yourButton' but you could select the button in any number of ways using jQuery selectors (google that to find plenty of tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

```
function tosser(){
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return "you lost";
    } else {
        return "you\'ve won";
    }
}
$("button").on("click",function(){
    alert(tosser());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question about jquery.

I'm assuming you can use jQuery then. Call the function on the click event:

```
function randomNumber(){
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.5) {
        console.log("you lost")
    } else {
        console.log("you've won");
    }
}

$("button").click(randomNumber);
```

Or:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function(){
    randomNumber();
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/KtJ2X/)

Also, you need to capitalize the `m` in `Math`.

Comment: @null He asks about jQuery in the first line, and he includes it in his fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXQ9U/3/)

Pass your function name in `onclick` event of your button

```
<button onclick="randomFunction();">click to call function randomFunction</button>
```

**Script**

```
function randomFunction() {
//here should be your code     
}
```

Comment: Inline javascript is so bleh.

Comment: Note the question is likely looking for a more jQuery-esque solution than inline JS calls.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

- Math.random() not math it's case sensitive
- $('#yourButton').click(function(){}) from DA. (This is useful)
- onclick="www.nu.nl" will not work if you want you can add
- 0.5 is a number in JS not 0,5
- There is soo small chance to win because 0.6187859538476914 :D number = number.toFixed(1);
- 1 represent decimal places
- `<Br>` doesnt need to be closed
- And something a lot useful is F12 in Chrome and Console tab

user181796 have a nice rest of day!

## JS

```
$('#Start').click(function(){
    number = Math.random();
    number = number.toFixed(1);
    if (number < 0.5) {
        console.log("you lost " + number);
    } else {
        console.log("you win " + number);
    }
});
```

## Head

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Html

```
<span> text box 1 </span>
 <input class = "styleYellow" type = "text"> </input> 
 <br> <br>
<span> text box 1 </span><input type = "text"> </input> 
 <br> </br>    

<button id="Start">Ga naar pagina 1</button>
<button id="I_dont_know">Ga naar pagina 2</button>
```